# Is it possible to block websites on Buffalo AirStation WCR-GN?

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall, blocking

Is it possible to block websites on a Buffalo AirStation WCR-GN? I've gone through every menu looking for anything that might do that and I can't, so I'm guessing this device is too primitive to be able to do that. Any ideas? Alternatively, does anyone know of a free app I can install on my Win 7 desktop that can block Facebook after a certain hour so that the kids aren't up all night?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Airstation's and other home routers are not able to do this kind of feature as its more of a Filtering tool or Next Gen Firewall process.

Depending on if they require other access and just not Facebook (web browsing) access you can use the account permissions to block out the time they should be off the PC:

Start and click Control Panel.
Under User Accounts and Family Safety, click set up parental controls for any user.
Click the account you want to add parental controls.
Click on Time limits.
Block out the time you don’t want the account to be able to login.
Press Ok.

If you wanted to allow access to the computer and just not the internet you can use the build-in firewall on the Airstation to the same affect of stopping traffic from the machine in question after a certain time. It normally works by binding the MAC address and setting a time period. However not 100% on that specific model but I can check the manual when I'm out of the office to provide more advice, please let me know.